# Is it possible to only animate half of a textbox in Microsoft Powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

So I assume the answer is no but I still want to try my luck here
So I have a powerpoint[image]

What I would like to do is to emphasis(animate)part of the textbox. But when I selected the text and animate it, the animation effect seems to apply to the whole textbox. Is there a fast way to achieve what I have in mind?

Comment: Why can't you bump two text boxes side by side and only animate the part you want to animate?

Comment: Good question. Because it is too time consuming to position the two boxs to look natual.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I animate only one word in a row?](https://superuser.com/questions/323556/how-do-i-animate-only-one-word-in-a-row)