# Split all letters in a word in Powerpoint

Tags: macros, microsoft-powerpoint, text-formatting, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, animation

I've come across this comment on a certain post that offers a solution for [splitting the words in a sentence](https://superuser.com/a/323662/1818648), however, I would need to split all the LETTERS in a WORD (or multiple words).

Is there a macro for that?

(edit: or if there is only a macro for splitting the WORDS in a SENTENCE please also comment below)

Super appreciate it!

[Reference picture for desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W47Hl.png)

*(the link in the solution have expired so I do not know how exactly how to execute it)*

Comment: You are looking for something, called OCR (Optical Character Recognition).

Comment: If by "split" you mean increase the distance between them, look into Font -> Character Spacing ->Expanded